# Drupal 7 - db_insert returns with error

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7

I try a simple insert query in **Drupal 7**, but it always return with error.
I tried out **db_insert**, **drupal_write_record**, and **db_query** also, but every functions return various errors.

I have a **tabledrag_menu** table:

[image]

I have an **$adat** array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Overview
    [weight] => 0
    [group] => left
    [checked] => 0
    [tid] => 96
    [nid] => 20
)
```

With var_dump it looks like this:

```
array(6) { ["name"]=>   string(8) "Overview"   ["weight"]=>   int(0)   ["group"]=>   string(4) "left"   ["checked"]=>   int(0)   ["tid"]=>   int(96)   ["nid"]=>   int(20) }
```

My code, which gives the error:

```
$id = db_insert('tabledrag_menu')->fields($adat)->execute();
```

When i use the **db_insert**, it return with this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'group, checked, tid, nid) VALUES ('Overview', '0', 'left', '0',
>   '96', '20')' at line 1: INSERT INTO {tabledrag_menu} (name, weight,
>   group, checked, tid, nid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =>
>   Overview [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   left [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 96
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 20 )

I think, this part causes the error, but i don't know how to fix it:

> VALUES ('Overview', '0', 'left', '0',
>   '96', '20')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group is MySql reserved word. Try using some other name for that field.

Comment: FYI, You can use `'\`group\`'` inside single quote (with the back tick). But if is possible I recommend to change the field name

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the single quote from the values that go inside integer columns.

E.g. change this

```
VALUES ('Overview', '0', 'left', '0', '96', '20')
```

to be something like:

```
VALUES ('Overview', 0, 'left', 0, 96, 20)
```